# Posting to a user's wall using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

O.K. this has been keeping me busy for 2 days now and I'm banging my brains out now.  I've posted it on forums, asked friends, googled it extensively and looked on stackoverflow.  I'm not the first to post this question but I couldn't find the answer among the responses so that's why I'm creating this new question.

this is what I'm trying to do : 
- I want to post a message to a user's wall as a Facebook-app in PHP.
- I want to do this server-to-server, so without the dialog box and any user-interaction (he could be mowing the lawn at that moment for all I care)
- This user has granted permission to my app, these permissions are: 1) manage_pages, 2) publish_stream, 3) read_stream
- I'm using the PHP Facebook SDK
- this is my code:

```
/* Facebook */ 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
));
/* string */ 
$accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
/* Array<string> */ 
$postFields = array("message"=>"test2", "access_token"=>$accessToken);

$facebook->api('/{the-id-of-the-facebook-user}/feed','post',$postFields);
```

this is the issue : 
I keep getting the following error : (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action.

This is a bullshit-message cause the user HAS authorized my app (That user also happens to be me and I checked all the permissions under apps, they're fine).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated cause I don't know where to look anymore. I know others posted this question before but the answers weren't satisfying.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It seems `publish_stream` problem. Make sure you have granted the `publish_stream` permission.

Comment: You should not be handling the access_token yourself – the SDK is perfectly capable of dealing with that on it’s own. But since you’re calling getAccessToken anyway – what value does it return? And what does the debug tool have to say about that token? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I have the publish_stream permission.  The token is a long string of letters and digits with a '|' somewhere in the middle.  The debugger returns the following when I enter the acces-token : 'Toepassings-ID: 
152046464919618 : Uitjezelf'

Comment: `publish_stream` means publishing to user's wall and to that user's friends wall [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/]. Are you sure you are posting to a wall of user who's given `publish_stream` permission or to one of his friends?

Comment: Yep, my Facebook-app should post to the wall of the facebook-user who granted this app permission to do so.  And he has given that permission.  I can check that cause I also manage that user's account.  It's says clearly under that applications-tab that this application has permission to post messages, status-updates, pictures and more.

Comment: Then try to re-authorize the app as something might got messy in tokens saved in cookies. And I assume the currently logged in user is a friend of the target user and also given the `publish_stream` permission, right?

Answer (score 0):

An app isn't allowed to post to a user's wall. You can only post to the wall as the user or as a different user (i.e. user-to-user). If you want to notify the user of something, you should use the app-to-user Requests API instead.

Comment: Posting as the user is what I'm trying to accomplish.  But the key-thing here is that it should be possible without the client-server authentication proces.  In other words :  the server hosting the website should be able to post a comment to the user's wall at any time.  To elaborate on what I want to do : I'm making a website for a customer.  This website has registered users how can post contents on that website.  The website also has a Facebook-page.  The website must be capable of posting the content posted by it's users on it's own facebook-page.

Comment: Ok. You can do this on server side by asking for 'publish_stream'. And then using the code from the above answer. You will need a long-lived access token if you want to continue posting to the users account once they have left your site.

Comment: I have the the publish stream permission.  But I understand that after the token expires, the user will have to authorize the app again in order for me to get a new token?  Is there no way to always post to a user's wall without requesting a new token?

Comment: You can follow this to get an `access_token` that doesn't expire as often: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what caused the error.  I tried a multitude of angles. In some cases I did manage to post something to the wall because the api returned an ID for the post which I could enter into the the browser to view the post (www.facebook.com/{the-id-of-the-post}).

The strange thing is however, that this post didn't appear on the timeline but on a separate page.  This page didn't have the user-profile at the top as is the case with a normal Facebook page. It also had a storyID parameter in the querystring. I couldn't figure out on what page I was and why it didn't just appear on the timeline.

The Facebook-page I was trying to post to was a Company-page.  But it wasn't attached to a 'normal' Facebook-page (of a person) as usually is the case. Eventually I did manage to post to the page of a page belonging the a 'normal' facebookpage.  So in most cases my code works now.  Rest to say that there's still much to improve in the Facebook SDK, it's documentation and that of http://developers.facebook.com.  It's not very clear how to perform certain operations.  I spent a lot of time once on a WP7 app for a Facebook-feature and now I spent at least 4 days to get this to work for this website.  I've decided to write my own SDK and expand it in the future.

Thanks to everyone for your time and help.  Stackoverflow rocks!

Answer (score -1):

If the feed you want to post is from the same user who has granted permissions you can put `me` instead of `{the-id-of-the-facebook-user}` . I just tried this and it worked:

```
$facebook->api(
    '/me/feed/',
    'post',
    array(
    'message' => "my message"
));
```

No need to post access_token. And the permissions the user gave were  only publish_actions

Comment: No, that is not the case, the post is from a facebook-app to another Facebook-user.  So we are talking about two different accounts.

Comment: @JustinvanSchaick Ahh, ok, now I understand what do you mean with "server-to-server". Sorry if I confused you with my answer.

Comment: @JustinvanSchaick Maybe you could read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677975/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-from-a-page-or-app

Comment: Thanks, had a look at it but I'm still stuck.  I tried all possible combinations and angles and I'm fresh out of options.  I'm beginning to think it's not possible.